# Determining if a number is an nth root

Tags: number-theory, cryptography

I am working on a proof that depends on if an adversary can determine if a number is an $nth$ power for some large prime $p$. My intuition tells me that for a sufficiently large value of $n$ this is impossible. However I am unaware of any theorems that state this. Could you point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean for given $x,n,p$ the adversary has to determine wheter $\exists y\colon y^n\equiv a\pmod p$? So you probably want $n\mid p-1$. Of course "impossible" is inadequate.

Comment: Given $n$, $p$, and the number $r$ can the adversary determine if $\exists$ $y$ such that $y^{n}\equiv r $(mod $p$)

Comment: Nope. Just the ability to distinguish if a number is an $nth$ power of something

Comment: I already know the exponent. I'm not trying to find what to the $nth$ power is the target number, I just want to know if the target number is an $nth$ power. Like using Legendre symbols for finding squares mod a prime, is there a similar method for arbitrary powers?

Comment: Any questions about the answer I posted?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple way to test whether $r$ is an $n$th power modulo $p$.

Given $n,p,r$, compute the least common multiple $s=nt$ of $n$ and $p-1$, then compute $r^t$. $r$ is an $n$th power modulo $p$ if and only if $r^t\equiv1\pmod p$.

Proof. Let $g$ be a primitive root mod $p$. Then $r=g^u$ for some $u$, and $r^t=g^{tu}\equiv1\pmod p$ if and only if $p-1$ divides $tu$, which makes $u$ a multiple of $n$.